# IOS : Remove a Persistent Storage in a Multithreading CoreData Implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Multithreading is definitely a tricky thing.

I have a Main Thread (AppDelegate), and then my app starts to send several other requests to sync some data according to some user actions. The data reads and modifies the CoreData. A Managed Object Conext is being created in each thread as Apple says.

Problem is, the "reset data base feature". That one that will simply remove all the data stored locally.

I'm doing that by removing the Persistent Store in the **AppDelegate** like so:

```
- (bool) resetCoreData
{

    //Remove the persistent Store.
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"insight.sqlite"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];

    //Borrar los conextos para que el APP lo cree despues
    for (NSManagedObject *ct in [self.managedObjectContext registeredObjects]) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:ct];
    }



    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,

                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    //Make new persistent store for future saves
    if (![self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
        // TODO: handling
    }

    return true;

}
```

Then, if try to fetch data from some other thread:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x1edba090 <x-coredata://5EAC46F6-54DA-480B-9B15-CB28248FD1CE/PlanResults/p7>''
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to release all `NSManagedObjectContext` objects before you delete your `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` object.  This needs to happen for all `NSManagedObjectContext` objects in all threads.  `NSManagedObjectContext` objects have a persistentStoreCoordinator property.

After deleting the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` file you can then re-create the `NSManagedObjectContext` objects.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer bbarnhart. Im using ARC. The MOC is being created at the beginning of each thread (a pointer and a alloc). As per I understand, as soon as the thread is over, those objects are killed. I've also tried explicitly set the MOC to nil and the end of each thread, but it does not have effect. Also, Im not deleting the Coordinator, Im deleting the PersistentStorage. I've also tried iterating all entities and manually deleting. Same crash.

Comment: In your code above, you are deleting your file storage and then attempting to delete objects.  That is a problem right there.